# Proof a numbertheoretical sum

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

Apparently the following holds:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} [x|k] \left(a_{m-k}(x) - a_{m-k-1}(x)\right) = 1-x[x|m]
$$
where $a_k(x) = k[x>k]$ and $[...]$ is the conditional bracket i.e. $=1$ if it is true and $0$ otherwise.

How should one proceed in proofing it?

Comment: This seems to be false in general. For $x\geq m+1$  the RHS equals $1-x$ and the LHS equals $m$.

Comment: I‘m not sure how you see that as for $x\geq m+1$ $x$ does neither divide $m$ nor $k$ for $k>0$. So LHS and RHS are 1.

Comment: In working out the 2 cases separately I am just not sure how to simplify the sum if e.g. x does not divide m. The only terms that appear are those for which x divides k. But then also $k$ has to be large enough in order for $x>m-k-1$. I‘m not sure I tackle the problem correctly.

Comment: Where does divisibility of $m$ or $k$ by $x$ play a role?

Comment: $[x|k] = [ x \, {\rm divides} \, k]$

Comment: So I missread the formula, I'm sorry.